# What does undefined local variable "sign_out_path" mean?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, class, ruby-on-rails-4

Firstly i don't have any error but :

**doubt:-** What does  `#<#<Class:0x48941b8>:0x2ad7448>` related to , if it is related to some specific `class` then why does it changes on reload
i have this error:

```
undefined local variable "sign_out_path"
```

Comment: Can you please post your complete error trace

Comment: The inspected value `#<#<Class:0x48941b8>:0x2ad7448>` means that the object is an instance of the instance of the `Class`. It is like the second derivative from the `Class` object, and in a rendering to the physics language it sounds like: `Class` object is similar to distance, `#<#<Class:0x48941b8>:0x2ad7448>` is similar to acceleration. 
What does it means in yuor context I don't know... provide sources, and logs

Answer (score 0):

`#<#<Class:0x48941b8>:0x2ad7448>`- This identifier was brought up because this is the scope of your error. In Ruby, every object, including classes, are assigned an arbitrary ID. The `0x48941b8` ID refers to your Class object ID.

The '0x2ad7448' ID is the reference identifier for the instance of the aforementioned class. I don't know what your complete error is, but I believe that you are calling a method to `sign_out_path` and because this `sign_out_path` had not been instantiated, you are getting this error.